# Unit test for XML Serialization

Tags: mocking, tdd, xml-serialization

I want to do TDD for the XML Serialization. I am not getting any help from anywhere. Please anyone explain me how to write unit test for XML serialization in C# using mock classes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need mock classes.

Here's a start:

```
public class SimpleClass {
    public string MyString;
}

[Test] public void SerializesSimpleObject() {
    var simpleClass = new SimpleClass { MyString = "test" };
    var serializer = new MySerializer();
    Assert.AreEqual(
        @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-16""?><SimpleClass xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""><MyString>test</MyString></SimpleClass>",
        serializer.Serialize(simpleClass));
}
```

Now make it green!